# Find out if any two elements in a list sum to a specific value in R

Tags: r, logic

This is a classic interview problem. Given a list `numbers` and a specific value `k`, find out if any two elements in `numbers` are equal to `k` when summed. How would one solve this in `r` in a single pass algorithm, rather than an exhaustive search?

In practical terms: write the most optimal function in `r` that receives a list `numbers` and a specific value `k`, returning `TRUE` if there are two elements in `numbers` that when summed equal to `k`. If there aren't, return `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem could be framed as: is there any `a` and `b` in `numbers`, such that:
`a + b = k`? Considering you already know `k`, and assuming there actually are two numbers that when summed are equal to `k`, one could assume that:

`a = k - b` or `b = k - a`.

So by doing `k - numbers` we would be essentially solving  the right sides of both the equations above. For example:

`numbers <- c(10, 12, 6, 3)` and `k <- 9`. `k - numbers` would return `c(-1, -3, 3, 6)`. See how 3 and 6 showed up?

To do all this in R, one could define a function

```
sum_finder <- function(numbers, k) {
    diff_sequence <- k - numbers
    condition <- any(numbers %in% diff_sequence)
    return(condition)
}
```

Or simply:

```
sum_finder <- function(numbers, k) {
    return(any(numbers %in% (k - numbers)))
}
```

**EDIT:** for benchmarking purposes, I'll be posting here the solutions posted so far and the performance results by using `microbenchmark::microbenchmark()`.

```
# as posted by @eduardokapp
function1 <- function(numbers, k) {
    any(numbers %in% (k - numbers))
}

# as posted by @AnilGoyal
function2 <- function(numbers, k) {
    any(apply(outer(numbers, numbers, `+`), 1, function(x){x == k}))
}

# Performance Comparison
numbers <- sample(500, 500)
k <- sample(500, 1)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
   function1(numbers, k),
   function2(numbers, k)
)
```

## Performance Comparison

Unit: MICROSECONDS

| expr | min | lq | mean | median | uq | max | neval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| function1(numbers, k) | 13.651 | 21.277 | 39.58225 | 27.4485 | 40.1905 | 277.256 | 100 |
| function2(numbers, k) | 5061.088 | 5805.186 | 10971.04516 | 7571.6030 | 13316.1325 | 47782.874 | 100 |

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with in-built functions only, in baseR

Let me demonstrate-

- Construct a sum matrix of number vector say `x` by using `outer` .  Let's name the intermediate result as `y`
- use apply to check `which` element in equal to desired number say `k`.  I used `arr.ind` argument = `T` so that output is indices in matrix format again.
- create a final matrix of `x` values where desired result is obtained

```
x <- 25:40
k <- 61
y <- outer(x, x, `+`)

matrix(x[which(apply(y, 1, function(x){x == k}), arr.ind = T)], ncol = 2)

      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   36   25
 [2,]   35   26
 [3,]   34   27
 [4,]   33   28
 [5,]   32   29
 [6,]   31   30
 [7,]   30   31
 [8,]   29   32
 [9,]   28   33
[10,]   27   34
[11,]   26   35
[12,]   25   36
```

We see 12 combination of values are satisfying you condition.

- **Note-1 for any commutative operation like `sum` in this case, the output will contain mirror images which you can filter out by taking above half values, if so desired.**
- **Note-2 If you also want to eliminate the values iterated over itself, you can set the `diag(y) <- 0` or `diag(y) <- NA` before proceeding further**

**Edit** in view of modified requirement, do this

```
x <- 25:40
k <- 61

sum(outer(x, x, `+`) == k) > 0
[1] TRUE

#OR
x <- 1:6
k <- 1

sum(outer(x, x, `+`) == k) > 0
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I believe the solution previously posted also uses base R and seems a bit more simple? Am I missing something? Thank you :)

Comment: May I also add, whatever operation  you use should return TRUE if there are any two elements satisfying the problem, or FALSE if there are not.

Comment: Reg your first comment - It is a personal choice as format of results in both cases are different.  Reg your second comment- actually if that is the only requirement, it is pretty simple and can be done without writing any custom function.  I am editing the answer to incorporate this requirement.

Comment: I may also like to add that it is good practice on SO, to accept whichever answer you feel as correct.  You can however, accept only one answer per question.  Still you can upvote as many answers per question as you feel right.

Comment: Sure! I was just curious if you thought the other answer wasn't right. I like your edit, didn't think about using `outer`. As a suggestion, maybe change `sum() > 0` for `any()`? Which is faster?

Comment: I just thought of `any() ` not aware of their speeds.  Try `bench::mark` for testing

Comment: I added a performance comparison to my answer. Feel free to add any suggestions. Thank you.